# How can I get Http response status code of my backend in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, http

I'm using angular with nodejs for the backend and I want to get my response from the backend server with the status code. For now I can obtain only the response data but I don't know how to get the status code. I need it to check how did the request get into the backend server.

This is my angular CityService code...

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class CityService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  API_URI = 'http://localhost:5000'

  getCity(id: string) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/City/${id}`);
  }
}
```

If I wanna call the getCity() function from somewhere in the angular project and get it's status code, how could I do it?

Thanks for the help!!!  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can access the status code by setting the option observe to 'response'. This gives you access to the whole response object, not just your data. Here is an example, i think it is self-explaining:

```
export class CityService {

    private API_URI = 'http://localhost:5000';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public getCity(id: string): Observable<City> {
        return this.http.get<City>(
            `${this.API_URI/City/${id}}`,
            { observe: 'response' }
        );
    }
}
```

Then in your component, where you use this service method, you can subscribe to the observable and read the status code like the following:

```
export class CityComponent {

    constructor(private cityService: CityService) { }

    public requestCity(id: string): void {
        const city$ = this.cityService.getCity(id);
        
        city$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res => {
            console.log('status: ' + res.status);
        });
    }
}
```